# Javascript calculator - eval() not working

Tags: javascript, calculator

I am trying to build a Javascript calculator but it is not working as the eval() is not working with the way I am using. In my console it is giving me the single value of input field. Following is the code that I am using.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="" disabled="true" id="inputField">
    <button id="btn5" value="5">5</button>
    <button id="btn2" value="2">2</button>
    <button id="operator" value="+">+</button>
    <button id="eval">=</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn5 = document.getElementById('btn5');
    var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
    var inpField = document.getElementById('inputField');
    var operator = document.getElementById('operator');
    var eval = document.getElementById('eval');

    btn5.addEventListener('click', btn5Function);
    btn2.addEventListener('click', btn2Function);
    operator.addEventListener('click', operatorFunction);
    eval.addEventListener('click', evalFunction)
    //inpField.value = "";

    function btn5Function() {
        inpField.value += btn5.value;
    }

    function btn2Function() {
        inpField.value += btn2.value;
    }

    function operatorFunction() {
        inpField.value += operator.value;
    }

    function evalFunction() {
        var storeVal = parseInt(inpField.value);
        console.log(storeVal);
        var cal = eval(storeVal);
        inpField.value = cal;
        }

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, outside the scope of the **strict mode**, you can override JavaScript *functions* and *keywords*. In this case, you are overriding the `eval` function:

```
var eval = document.getElementById('eval');
```

Renaming that variable should cause your problems to fade away.

I also noticed that you are not 100% confident about the use of the `parseInt` function, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: not working. It is giving me the number which is pressed first. For example, if I press '5' then '+' then '2', it is giving me only '5'.

Comment: Because you are using `parseInt`. `parseInt` looks for numbers from left to right and it stops when it meets a not-numeric character. So if you have `2+3` the function reads the first character `2` and it's ok, then it meets a not number character `+` and it stops here and returns 2.

You don't need to convert the value to an integer because `eval` expects a string

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're trying to parseInt on string which consists of operator, hence the issue:

```
var storeVal = parseInt(inpField.value);  <-- this will not work.
```